# Why does std::vector::iterator::operator-> only drill down one level?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, drilldown

This code fails to compile:

```
void foo(vector<unique_ptr<pair<int, int>>> bar)
{
    bar.begin()->first;
}
```

What's the problem here? Shouldn't `operator->` drill down until `pair`?

Comment: "_Shouldn't `operator->` drill down until `pair`?_" No. Why should it? It returns the underlying element, which is `unique_ptr<pair<int, int>>`.

Comment: Which has its own `operator->`, so normally C++ calls that (usually called `operator->`'s drill down behavior.

Comment: Just because a class has a `operator->` doesn't mean that it should be called automatically. How would the compiler know when to call it vs. when to not? How would the compiler know you want the `pair` inside it, and not the `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Have you tried bar[0]->first ?

Comment: @HazemAbaza Of course I know I *could* just dereference the iterator and proceed, but it was surprising since I thought `operator->` kept going until it hit a class which doesn't have one.

Comment: @Artikash "_I thought `operator->` kept going until it hit a class which doesn't have one._" What gave you such an idea? Where did you read that it worked this way? As already stated in the comments: what if you didn't recurse to the bottom? How would you avoid such recursing, if this was the behavior?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Because I have written a class which relied on that behavior: https://github.com/Artikash/Textractor/blob/master/include/common.h#L62 I thought you had to call `.operator->().operator->()...` manually if you wanted to control it.

Comment: @Artikash "_I have written a class which relied on that behavior_" is a recursive argument. I asked, where, in which documentation, C++ standard, etc., have you read that this is the expected behavior? Hence, what gave you this idea? Note: calls `x->y`, and `x.operator->()->y` are equivalent. The first is merely syntactic sugar for the second.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I don't remember what I was thinking when I wrote that class a year ago lol. What I do know is when I use that class now it does seem to behave like that: `Synchronized<std::pair<int,int>>(0,0)->first` does compile "since it successfully drills down until `pair` which doesn't have `operator->` so it stops then". That's what I thought, not realizing it actually stops at the second level because that level returns a raw pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't `operator->` drill down until `pair`?

The recursion of `operator ->` only works until you get a pointer type.  Once that happens the recursion stops and you access what that pointer points to.  In this case `std::vector::iterator::operator->` returns a `unique_ptr<pair<int, int>>*` as that pointer type of the element in the vector.  Once you hit that pointer, you are left accessing the members of the `unique_ptr`, not the `pair<int, int>` it points to.

You can get what you want using

```
(*bar.begin())->first;
```

so now you are using `operator->` of `unique_ptr<pair<int, int>>`.